# Windows 10 stretches taskbar icons when connected to external monitor

Tags: windows-10, multiple-monitors, taskbar

I set my taskbar to "Never combine" so that the individual windows are shown. As you can see in the image, when I connect to an external monitor, it stretches the taskbar icons. Interestingly, this happens only when I boot my laptop, and afterwards connect the monitors. If I were to boot with the monitors connected beforehand, this problem doesn't happen. I see this behaviors on all my external monitors, so I don't think it's a monitor issue.

I've tried unplugging and re-plugging the monitors, but it doesn't fix it. The only solution is to reboot the computer, which does fix the issue. Is there anything I can do to fix this without a reboot? Eg script to refresh/restart the taskbar or tweak the settings/registry?

[image]

Three monitors connected, all of them 1920x1080 and scaling is 100%
for all of them:

[image]

Comment: What are the resolutions of all the monitors and their scaling (Settings > System > Display)? How is the desktop defined over the external monitor?

Comment: 3 monitors connected, all of them 1920x1080. Scaling is 100% for all of them. Not sure how to check the way desktop is defined over the external monitors. Do you mean the orientations?

Comment: I mean the multi-monitor configuration found in *Settings > System > Display*.

Comment: Here it is: https://imgur.com/GgRLiyC

Comment: Use `regedit` and navigate to key `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Control Panel\Desktop\WindowMetrics`. Do you have a value named `MinWidth`? If you do, export the key for safe keeping and try to delete this value and reboot.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have that key, here's a snippet of WindowMetrics folder: https://imgur.com/aWcyJqJ

Comment: Any chance restarting Explorer fixes it?